# Override MouseMove event in F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

How do I override the MouseMove (or any mouse event for that matter) in F#, similar to how it's done in C#? Meaning I want to write something like this, just to get the current mouse coordinates.

```
override form.MouseMove e = 
    mouseX = e.X
    mouseY = e.Y
```

Edit: basically I want to access the MouseEventArgs, and in this code the argument e is interpreted as PaintEventArgs instead.

Second Edit: This code actually works, just had another code block with an override on the OnPaint event, so apparently I couldn't use the same event argument variable (e) for both overrides in F#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the method you want is called `OnMouseMove`.

```
type MyForm() =
    inherit Form()
    override this.OnMouseMove(e) = printfn "Mouse is at %d %d" e.X e.Y
```

Comment: Looks to work the same as what I initially posted, doing this the argument e passed is interpreted as PaintEventArgs, so I don't get the MouseEventArgs I want and cannot access the current mouse coordinates.

Comment: Okay, problem solved, had this code right under an override of the OnPaint event, so I guess I got the e argument from that override statement (which is really weird).. Atleast got it to work now, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to overriding the virtual method in a derived class, you could use a F# object expression to achieve the same result. This is useful to create an instance of overridden behavior without the need to define a derived class.

```
let mutable mouseLoc = Point()
let myForm = {
    new Form() with
        override __.OnMouseMove args =
            mouseLoc <- args.Location }
```